# How to add filter in http get flutter?

Tags: http, dart, get, flutter

I really want know how to add filter having fields, where, limit, skip and so on using darts http package.

I already try using uri but ... it only accepts `Map<String, String>`. But my filter is more deep than that.

When using js it was fine ....but using in flutter is not working because of it's strongly typed property.

Comment: Please add more details and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go deeply into Maps , maps can eccept more than one layer , lets say if your filter struct like this

```
-color:
--red ,
-size:
--small
```

then you need to `Map<String, String>`

lets go deeply into more complicated level

```
-color:
--backColor:
---red
--fromColor:
---orange
-size:
--width:
---10CM
--height:
---10CM
```

then you should use a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`
this mean you can go deeper into your Map as you want
also map can handle "dynamic" data type if you dont expect one kind of data type Map
the "dynamic" key word can be another map or even a list of Maps !

see this real dart example:

```
Map<String, String> levelOne = {"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"}

Map<String, dynamic> levelTow = {"key1" : "value1", "key2" : levelOne}

Map<String, dynamic> levelThree = {"key1" : "value1", "key2" : levelTow}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but ... what about having these type of filter

`filter = {
      limit: 100,
      skip: 0,
      order: "createdAt DESC",
        where: {
          "title": "accountant"
        },
        fields: [
          "id",
          "name",
          "address"
        ]
    };`

Comment: as a dart code its correct Map , and you can create it using UI elements events , 
the second step is encode this map (to json) then you well send it directly to server using http, 
dart has a json encoder `json.encode(YourMap)`
after encode it , send the json array as a normal parameter using POST [https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http]
in your back end you can convert the json received to your server language 
as example , php has "json_decode" function , to decode json objects
php example code `$filters = json_decode($_POST["filters"]);`